# Loading full document via curl

Tags: php, html, curl

Hello i have problem with loading page via curl. Page html looks like this

```
<!--showModel--><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...
```

and then curl load page i get only

```
<!--showModel-->
```

how can i load full page?

php code looks like this

```
$agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: does your page HTML loads dynamically? are you using any JS platform such as AngularJS ?